# How to add something to a linked list

Tags: c++, class, pointers, linked-list, memory-address

I'm just a little bit confused about an error I'm getting.  I've made a class called "SensorNode", and each SensorNode has a linked list of sensors.  One data member of SensorNode is a SensorBlock(the linked list) pointer called mySensors.  mySensors is supposed to point to the first sensor in the linked list of sensors owned by the sensor node it's in.  Here's the class declaration for SensorNode:

```
class SensorNode {
    char* NodeName;
    int NodeID;
    LOCATION Node1;
    float batt;
    int func;
    SensorBlock *mySensors;


public:
    SensorNode(char *n, float x, float y, float z, int i, float ah);
    void print();
    void setOK(int o);
    int getOK();
    void setLOC(float longi, float lat, float h);
    int amIThisSensorNode(char *n);
    void addSensorToNode(sensor *s);
};
```

and here's the class declaration for SensorBlock:

```
class SensorBlock {

    friend class SensorNode;
    SensorBlock * LLelement;
    sensor * SensEl;
};
```

my problem is with my void addSensorToNode(sensor *s) function.  Argument s points to a sensor which is supposed to be added to the end of the list of sensors that belong to that node.  And I can't figure out how to do that since it's not a new sensor that I'm creating and adding, but a pointer to a sensor that I'm adding.

Here's what I have so far:

```
void SensorNode::addSensorToNode(sensor *s) {
    if(mySensors == '\0') //mySensors is first initialized to NULL
    {
        mySensors = s; //I get an error on this line.
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

I don't know how to fix the error I get on that above line, and I don't know what to put in the "else" when mySensors is no longer equal to null.  If I solved the above error I might be able to better understand the addition process for a new sensor.  Thank you in advance for any help you can offer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mySensors = s` should be `mySensors.SensEl= s`

Because mySensors  is of type `SensorBlock` while s is a `sensor`

```
void SensorNode::addSensorToNode(sensor *s) {
    if(mySensors == NULL) //mySensors is first initialized to NULL
    {
        mySensors = new SensorBlock();
        mySensors->SensEl = s; //I get an error on this line.
        mySensors->LLelement = NULL;
    }
    else {

       SensorBlock newBlock = new SensorBlock();
       newBlock->SensEl = s;
       newBlock->LLelement = NULL;
       mySensors->LLelement = newBlock;

    }
}
```

Comment: *smacks head* rookie mistake, I must be tired, thank you.  I think it actually needs to be mySensors->SensEl = s;  But same basic idea.  Thanks for pointing it out to me

Comment: What do I put in the else for when it's not the very start of the linked list?

Comment: @Acoustic, edited the answer, but I think you can simplify the data structure by unifying sensor class and SensorBlock

Comment: ^Thanks for adding the else statement stuff!  Unfortunately I get an error: "No viable conversion from 'SensorBlock *' to 'SensorBlock'".  Any idea what that means? And you're right about the unification, but unfortunately this is for an assignment and I can't change the class :/